# how do i make sure that only one reaction can be added to a message?

Tags: discord.js

I am creating a role reaction bot and I want that if a member has already clicked on a reaction and clicks another it removes the previous one and the role associated with it and gives him the role that corresponds to the last one clicked (there are 15 reactions available) , I was writing code similar to this:

```js
let msg = reaction.message;
let msgGuild = msg.guild;
let userGuild = msgGuild.members.cache.get(user.id);
let userRole = userGuild.roles;
if(reaction.message.channel.id === "764148072498200589") {
   if(reaction.emoji.name === "RedRoleID") {
      if(userRole.cache.has("BaseRoleID")) {
          userRole.remove("BaseRoleID");
          userRole.add("RedRoleID");
      } else if(userRole.cache.has("OrangeRoleID")) {
          userRole.remove("OrangeRoleID");
          userRole.add("RedRoleID");
      }
   };
};
```

is there an easier and shorter way to do what I want without creating an `else if` for each role?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could probably make an array of all the emoji names, then use `Array.prototype.forEach` to check all of them.

```js
let { emoji, message, message: { guild, channel }} = reaction;
let { roles } = guild.member(user.id);
const emojis = ['BaseRoleID', 'RedRoleID', 'OrangeRoleID', 'etc'];
if (channel.id === '764148072498200589') {
 emojis.forEach((id) => (roles.cache.has(id) ? roles.remove(id) : id));
 roles.add(emoji.name);
}
```

---

Edit: My mistake, I thought you had named the emojis as the corresponding role IDs. Here's an alternate method if you do not want to do that:

```js
let { emoji, message, message: { guild, channel }} = reaction;
let { roles } = guild.member(user.id);
const emojis = [
  { emote: 'EmojiID', role: 'RoleID' }, 
  'continue this pattern for all roles and emotes'
];

if (channel.id === '764148072498200589') {
  emojis.forEach(({ emote, role }) => {
    if (roles.cache.has(role))
      return roles.remove(role)
    if (emoji.id === emote) roles.add(role)
  });
};
```

Comment: so to make it work I have to rename the reactions with the same name as the role?

Comment: no, right now the name of the emoji should be the id of the role. Isn't that what you were already doing?

Comment: I have now seen your change and applied it, there is a small problem, it gives me all the roles I specified and not just the one that corresponds to the reaction I clicked

Comment: That's my fault, I accidentally overwrote a variable. Try it again.